# Error while using ionic cordova build android

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build my ionic project using `ionic cordova build android` it stuck here. I thought some of my project files have broken and tried to build some of my older projects and it is same with those projects too. I've also tried using `ionic cordova run android` and `--prod` but nothing works. its not even showing error why it got stuck. but if I create a new project and build it, it is building successfully.

here is my console

[image]

Comment: what version of Java, Gradle, ionic are you using? run command `ionic info` and add result in your question.

Comment: ionic version `6.16.1` , java version `1.8.0_221` & gradle `7.0.2`

Comment: try downgrading your ionic to 5.x version and see if it works.